# Is “If white privilege exists, why did Elizabeth Warren pretend to be an Indian?" a fallacy, and if so, which one?

Tags: fallacies

I recently came across the meme below. I consider it a logical fallacy (the existence of one use of a socioeconomic tool other than white privilege does not preclude the existence of white privilege).

Is this an example of a named logical fallacy? Which one?

[image]

Comment: There's a much more obvious fallacy at work as well: she didn't. :)  She's always been clear that this was one ancestor some distance back, passed on as oral family history.

Comment: @Graham - Sadly, she did list her race as "American Indian" on her Texas State Bar card, in her own handwriting: https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/elizabeth-warren-indian-card/ And allowed herself to be listed as a minority for years in the AALS desk book. This despite it being vague oral history in her family (prior to the DNA test, which tribes don't accept) and her not having any tangible links to any tribe. It's unfortunate, and she's apologized for it, and it's nothing to the outrageous and provably-false claims of some other politicians, but...sadly, she did do it.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder In Warren's defense, "American Indian" is often listed as a race on official forms and documents, and there is generally no "minimum DNA requirement" for racial membership. Unfortunately, there is no consensus, even among the tribes, on what requirements must be met to call oneself a Native American. Most Americans who consider themselves white have no native blood. Warren has some. It would be a stretch to say she was lying.

Comment: "All dogs have 4 legs", "My cat has 4 legs", "Therefore my cat is a dog". White privilege is not the only way politicans can gain an advantage.

Comment: It's like asking "if you already have drain cleaner why did you ask for a glass of orange juice?", i.e. the drain cleaner is the wrong tool to reduce thirst. Obviously she felt that being Native American would confer some different benefit to white privilege, while not necessarily giving up the latter anyway.

Comment: Note that this rhetorical question presumes facts not in evidence. An explicit premise is that she pretended which by definition is characterizing contrary to fact. Not only are there implicit premises, but an explicit premise itself is presumes something likely to be true, and in this case is a form of poisoning the well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_the_well

Comment: @DoctorDestructo - I didn't say she was lying. (I guess the meme -- which, for the avoidance of doubt, is rubbish -- sort of does say that, via the word "pretend," though, which I didn't pick up on.) I just countered the assertion that "she didn't" make the claim that she was "American Indian."

Comment: @DoctorDestructo I've got 2% West African DNA, and mitochondrial DNA that points to what is now Burkina Faso.  By your "*It would be a stretch to say she was lying*" logic, I can claim African ancestry with a straight face, my mother even more so.  But that's highly absurd.

Comment: @RonJohn I would not consider it absurd for you or anyone else to claim African ancestry. In fact, I believe most anthropologists would consider it absurd for you not to claim African ancestry.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo my comment had a typo.  I should have written, "I can claim **to be** African with a straight face".  My mistake.

Comment: @RonJohn You're African only if you come from Africa. However, if you have a higher percentage of indigenous African DNA than people who do not claim to be black, then you may be able to make a credible claim that you're black.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo how about Afro-Caribbean?  (That's where my African genes lived after being sold into slavery in Africa.)

Comment: @RonJohn I don't think you'll find an "Afro-Caribbean" checkbox on most forms. In my experience it's usually limited to American indian, Asian, black, Pacific Islander, white, and multiracial (and sometimes Hispanic, though that is considered an ethnicity nowadays). Usually, you're expected to tick whichever box you think applies to you.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo the US Census has an Other box.  I could also claim (literal) Hispanic, through a great-grandfather.  Allowing Warren to do what she did without any push-back opens a serious can of worms.  https://news.harvard.edu/gazette/story/2010/12/one-drop-rule-persists/ "The legal notion of hypodescent has been upheld as recently as 1985, when a Louisiana court ruled that a woman with a black great-great-great-great-grandmother could not identify herself as “white” on her passport."  According to that, **I'm black.**

Comment: Compare: “If it’s such an advantage to be a trust-fund baby, why do they all claim to be self-made men?" You can even insert the name of another politician there if you feel like it.

Comment: I think whether the joke works or not for you depends more on your factual beliefs about the world than on a logical fallacy. Most Republicans say that discrimination against white people is a bigger problem than discrimination against people of color. So the knock on her in right-wing circles is that they think she called herself Cherokee to advance her career. The punch line is the implied admission that being white is a disadvantage.

Comment: A Democrat, on the other hand, thinks that a Native who grew up in poverty on a reservation would have major disadvantages in life, and a white person calling herself Cherokee would not have to actually give up any advantages she got from her skin color, or what school she went to, or where she grew up, or how much money her family had, etc. They also don’t think it helped her career to exoticize herself that way. So, to them, that joke might seem like a different kind of grievance-based identity politics.

Comment: Unfortunately, that observation doesn’t really say much of *philosophical* interest.

Comment: your question is meant to be inflammatory and meant to provoke political opinions. Please read the forum rules.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I disagree. The question of asking what fallacy something is, is not meant to be inflammatory and provoke  political opinions. Just because it included a political official and some commenters decided to go that direction, does not mean that was the intent. They could have just as easily responded with what the actual fallacy is, if any exists - some answers do avoid the political discussion. — Your comment, on the other hand, may use juvenile reasoning, demonstrate bias, and inability to see the forest from the trees. Please don’t project or assert things you don’t know

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda While I made an effort to reply seriously, I don’t for an instant believe that a question about what informal rhetorical fallacy a stand-up comic is committing in his routine about a politician is being asked in good faith. Come on, it’s an effort to get a dig at a politician onto the front page of a high-traffic website.

Comment: @Davislor I don't think the question is about why this joke 'works' or not.  I think it's pretty obvious what the implication is, it's not nuanced in any way.  My personal experience tells me this is the kind of 'logic' that is used to 'prove' things in certain circles.  Identifying the specific rhetorical trick here is completely valid.

Comment: It's not a fallacy but just bad reasoning: anecdotal evidence isn't evidence. That's just as much a fallacy as spreading blatant lies as truths.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda: The question was not meant to incite political discussion or generate volume on the home page, despite the comments under the question. :) I was looking for the specific logical fallacy at work, and the answer I accepted was perfect (with a lot of other answers providing additional color/nuance). Thanks all for the information!

Comment: A somewhat related example is Barack Obama stating he's African American despite being equally black and white and his father being a first-generation African immigrant. There's a grain of truth in this joke, even if it has elements of fallacy.

Comment: Maybe this will help:  https://thebestschools.org/magazine/15-logical-fallacies-know/

Comment: Even if there weren't a fallacy, you have just one data-point. Even without all the fallacies a response could be "Warren doesn't believe there to be white privilege". That doesn't extrapolate to wider society.

Comment: I think this is a false dichotomy or trichotomy or whatever. It thinks that you fake being Indian just for the privilege and benefits, but it ignores all the other possible reasons. She faked being India by accident (see J Crowder's comment). This meme ignored the other possible reasons and thus is an example of this fallacy.

Comment: First of all it’s a question. But lets say the implication is: “Her pretending to be nonwhite casts doubt on the existence of white privilege.” I see no fallacy there. Thats why you cant figure out which one it is. Unless you mean he is implying that it is not evidence but proof. If you assume that than the fallacy is assumption of one causal factor

Comment: Probably repeating what others have said but I think it’s 3 questions stacked and it really could be of benefit to everybody to phrase it that way, if the OP would be ok with it. “1. What is being implied, by the meme? 2. Is the claim true or false? Why? 3. Does the truth/falsehood of the claim exhibit a characteristic (argument) pattern of some kind?” I would actually advocate trying to phrase the question a bit more openly, but not sure if the idea would not be met well by others. (I think we could claim the question is garnering 2 types of answers: what is white privilege

Comment: vs. argumentative analysis. I usually try to be really supportive of all questions, but maybe it can be claimed the question could just laxen its assumptions. By analogy, what if someone asked, “Someone said that abortion is a sin. What fallacy is that?” It may be ok editorial practice to ask that a question state its assumptions a little more frontally, for example, even just a subtle change to “Assuming that this is false, because (…), what fallacy would that be?”

Answer (score 72, accepted):

“If you are so smart why aren't you rich?” “If this country is so bad why don't you leave?” “If it is so easy why aren't you doing it?” These types of rhetorical barbs rely on what is called an [enthymeme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthymeme), and argument with implicit parts. If X then why not Y? relies on Y not being in evidence, and suggests that X must not be the case. Enthymemes can be valid, when reconstructed, but if there is an error it is typically in presuming that X implies Y.

This case certainly is a non-sequitur, but that is a very broad category. Anything invalid is a non-sequitur. But *why* is it invalid? The reconstructed argument would be something like this: white privilege is *the only* way to benefit from race; Warren sought such benefits by claiming to be Indian, not white; hence, there is no white privilege.

But, of course, there is more than one way to benefit from race, by being white *and* by being non-white. Overlooking additional possibilities is generally known as a [false dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma). In this case, it is an even more specific kind of overlooking: overlooking (or ignoring) additional causes for the observed action. This is known as the [fallacy of a single cause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_the_single_cause), or causal oversimplification. Indeed, this is the most common explanation for If X then why not Y?, when it is a genuine question, and the reason for it being a fallacy when not X is the implied conclusion.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this would be the opposite of an enthymeme, based on how you described them? It's saying that because Elizabeth Warren pretended to be a Native American, white privilege must not exist (because if it did exist, she would have been able to benefit from that instead).

Comment: @nick012000 I think they're saying that the form of the argument is an enthymeme, but it fails because the assumptions are not true.

Comment: @nick012000 Enthymeme is an argument which is not fully spelled out, it is often the form of rhetorical insinuations. In this case Y is assumed to be known to the audience, and the conclusion (not X) is only suggested, not stated.

Comment: As I see it, the reasoning implied by the question is **valid** (in terms of its propositional logic structure), using Modus Tollens (p→q, ¬q, ∴¬p), where p = "White Privilege exists" and q = "a person will self-identify as White whenever possible".  If there is a fallacy, it's an **informal** fallacy based on questionable premises (such as False Dillemma or Single Cause, which you correctly identified).

Comment: downvoted your answer because the nature of the question is only meant to rile the forum into a political discussion. The question could have been asked in a philosophical manner without injecting political discourse.

Comment: The question is by its nature meant to be inflammatory and is not appropriate for this forum.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - No, all due respect, that's your misinterpretation as others have pointed out in the comments on the question. The question is quite clearly asking what the fallacy is, not intentionally inflammatory. But even if the question *were* intentionally inflammatory, downvoting all the *answers* to it is not appropriate.

Comment: Downvoting an answer because you don't like the question is inappropriate, @SwamiVishwananda

Comment: Your analysis assumed the implication was, “her pretending to be nonwhite is proof of lack of white priv”. But if it was “her pretending to be nonwhite is evidence”, then theres no fallacy. Political debates throw evidence rarely proof. I think it’s exaggerating what is implied to interpret that way. I dont see a “fallacy”.

Comment: Your first two questions can only be answered properly with a slap in the face. The third one is absolutely legitimate in many cases.

Comment: @gnasher729 "*Thanks. I needed that.*"

Answer (score 10):

This is a good example of *[Tu quoque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_quoque)* (the appeal to hypocrisy): a fallacy that intends to discredit the opponent's argument by asserting the opponent's failure to act consistently in accordance with its conclusion(s).

The pattern is:

1. Person A makes claim X.
2. Person B asserts that A's actions or past claims are inconsistent with the truth of claim X.
3. Therefore, X is false.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy SE! This is an excellent example of how to answer a "what fallacy" question!

Answer (score 9):

I see a couple of contenders:

#### The [anecdotal fallacy](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/anecdotal):

> [Using] personal experience or an isolated example instead of a sound argument or compelling evidence.

Even if it's true that Elizabeth Warren claimed to be Native American on occasion ([snopes link](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/elizabeth-warren-indian-card/)), that doesn't mean white privilege doesn't exist. People are complex and do things for all kinds of different reasons, or even no reason at all.

#### The [false dilemma](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/black-or-white) or "black and white" fallacy:

> [Presenting] two alternative states as the only possibilities, when in fact more possibilities exist.

The existence of white privilege and Elizabeth Warren identifying as Native American are not mutually-exclusive possibilities.

Comment: fair and to the point: it's cherry picking

Comment: It's also the case that someone can claim to be native american on a form and continue to benefit from white privilege.  It's unlikely to have changed the way people perceived her or interacted with her, even if they were aware she had done this which I think few people did.

Comment: @some_guy632 - Absolutely. My view of Warren's identification on her Texas Bar card would be completely different if she'd had a tangible connection to a tribe. (Not that my view of her identification is important.)

Comment: It's a clear cut case of a false dilemma to me.

Comment: Again, you decided the implication was “this is proof” when it could have been “this is evidence”. It’s a question. Anecdotes *are* evidence. Depending on how they are collected and/or presented.. randomly without design, randomized, or systematically.. they can be good or bad evidence. Most people’s decisions are probably mostly anecdotally based

Comment: @AlBrown - Are you confusing me with someone else? This is literally the only answer I've ever posted on this site, but the "again" makes me think you're thinking of someone else. Or was there a missing `@`? (I'm also not quite seeing how the comment relates to the answer, but it's entirely possible I'm just being a bit slow. :-) )

Comment: Youre right. My mistake. Remove the “again” and should make sense. Or ignore me, either way. But definitely have a good day.

Answer (score 7):

It isn't a fallacy because it isn't a logical statement; it is a rhetorical question.

It could be an malicious question along the lines of "Have you stopped beating your wife yet?" where the question includes assumptions that you would validate by answering anything; but that isn't the case here as you yourself point out by answering "the existence of one use of a socioeconomic tool other than white privilege does not preclude the existence of white privilege".

The question implies a logical proof, but since it doesn't flesh it out we are left with guessing what it would be and can't say that it would be a fallacy. We *could* construct any fallacy we want from it, but that would be disingenuous, akin to making a straw-man fallacy of our own.

We can tell that the overall structure of the proof would be a proof by  contradiction, starting with `"white privilege"`. That is probably why people think "fallacy"; but `A ∧ ¬A` isn't a fallacy.

Some people may say that the implied premises are false, for instance that Elisabeth Warren pretended to be indian or that pretending to be indian causes you to lose white privilege. That doesn't make it a fallacy, just counter factual/false.

It is true that the sentiment implies a something that appears wrong somehow; but that is how it is a joke or a meme.

Comment: It's clearly a rhetorical question which contains an inference. The intent of a comedian (or a meme crafted to look as if...) is not to elicit information, but declare a statement. Syntax is often ambiguous, and meaning must be derived from context, intonation, etc.

Comment: The question is built on a fallacy. "If you didn't drink coffee this morning, then why aren't you in jail?" is a question built on the premise of going to jail if you didn't drink coffee in the morning. The question exists specifically to state its underlying premise, which is a fallacy.

Comment: It's not simply a question. It implies a statement. The implication is "White privilege does not exist, because Elizabeth Warren pretended to be an Indian."

Comment: @JD Indeed language is ambiguous and interpretation is required. You need to make a charitable interpretation though, in this case I interpret the implied fallacy as "the joke" and the message as… well the _actual_ text; why doesn't she want to cash in on "white privilege"?. It you _don't_ make an effort for a charitable interpretation then that in itself is a strawman fallacy.

Comment: @Odalrick I did make a charitable interpretation which is: Warren pretended to be an Indian. This attribution of intent, as 'pretend' is an intentional departure of characterizing something accurately, is specious. For whatever idiocy of identity politics is present in her characterizing her self as Native American, for the claim to be that she did so with the intent to deceive is fallacious, and would be an obvious bias since no evidence supports it.

Comment: @JD I don't quite understand what you mean to say. "Warren pretended to be an Indian"; yes, I agree. You dislike the use of "pretend"? I don't. It is maybe not completely accurate, but it conveys the meaning well enough, and nobody expects a rhetorical question to contain _all_ the information anyway. I will add "rhetorical" to my answer, it is more accurate.

Comment: The interpretation is Warren pretended. My claim is that the claim is wrong, and the argument to it is fallacy.

Comment: @JD Oh, I understand. You see a false premise and think "fallacy", however that is not how it works in logic. A statement can be valid without being true; and I should update my answer. That applies only in formal logic however; do you know of any other uses of "fallacy" where the meaning is different?

Comment: @Odalrick You have some enthymemes that are roadblocks to comprehension. First is that propositions can valid or invalid. Validity and soundness are properties of arguments. Remember, propositions and their instantiation, statements, are true and false, and the logical structures they belong to are examined for validity and soundness. Second, that applies to formal and informal inference. Third, the categories fallacy and unsound or invalid inference are not mutually exclusive. A fallacy is ANY persuasive, but unsound or invalid form of reason by def'n.

Comment: This meme exploits several biases of the mind, but setting aside the cognitive origins of fallacy, it is specious because it essentially is an argument as such: 1) Warren intentionally claimed a racial identity she does not possess 2) (Claiming a puportedly inferior racial category when one possess a superior one is proof the superior one enjoys no advantage) 3) Therefore, the superior racial identity is not superior. There are all sorts of problems with this argument, so it is  both invalid and unsound.

Comment: To accuse Warren of intentionally misrepresenting herself (see Hanlon's razor) is ad hominen. To presume the second premise is non-sequitur. 3) To combine premises one and two is a sort of fallacy fallacy. Given the image, the argument desguised as a question, and the three distinct fallacies it embodies, this meme qualifies arguably for propaganda. It could very well be that a foreign intelligence agency created this meme to be divisive. https://news.clearancejobs.com/2017/09/12/foreign-intelligence-services-used-social-media-to-target-clearance-holders/

Comment: @JD You _really_ want there to be a fallacy here, don't you. :) 1) Ad hominem isn't just any insult. "Homer is stupid. Therefore his views on donuts are wrong." is an ad hominem, "Homer is stupid. Stupid people don't write have PhDs. Therefore Homer has no PhD." isn't ad hominem; despite both saying "Homer is stupid". 2) is a non-sequitur because _you_ wrote it that way. 3) A fallacy fallacy? Because the previous statements are fallacies, the conclusion is correct? I think you mean something other than what I understand "fallacy fallacy" to be… 3) is _valid_.

Comment: @JD Things _can_ be wrong without being a fallacy you know. At least in formal logic and as I said, that is my only source for the meaning of fallacies.

Comment: It's not a question of want. It is. See the number one rated answer (Conifold's) whose reputation and votes on this question are well deserved. As far as fallacy fallacy, if you weren't aware that validity is not a property of propositions (a Week 1 concept in Logic 101) I suggest educated persons would find your claims more suspect than mine. However, here's my answer on fallacy fallacy. Feel free to critique. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/68267/when-does-a-fallacy-fallacy-apply/68288#68288 Being a skeptic doesn't absolve you of the requirement of self-skepticism.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101026/discussion-between-odalrick-and-j-d).

Comment: Yes fallacy is overplayed. It’s esp bad here because first you have to decide whats being implied. If you say hes implying thats evidence, or proof? And of what... her hypocrisy, or the white priv claim in general, or her inconsistent behavior vs expressed belief. I imagine the politics drove the desire to say “fallacy haha” more than the logic.

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of possible logical fallacies here, depending on exactly what is meant and what assumptions you make about the implied audience.

If you read the meme as:

> ... why did Elizabeth Warren ***ever*** pretend to be...

Then the joke is attempting to poke holes in the argument that white privilege is always superior to any form of minority privilege.

The joke seems to be broadly and obliquely referring to "the Left", who probably do not hold quite such a broad interpretation of white privilege, in which case, it is a **strawman**.
You could also claim a **no true scotsman** (all Democrats believe that white privilege...) if you want to try and restrict the audience to only people who believe in such a broad definition but still say "Democrats" or "the Left".
At the very least, it's a **non sequitur** since the joke does not identify the audience whose belief on white privilege is necessary to know in order to know the resulting accuracy of the joke.

Finally, if you really do believe that all Democrats actually hold such a broad view of white privilege, and are willing to assume the audience as Democrats or "the Left", then it's still a **claim to improper or biased authority** because Elizabeth Warren could have a variety of reasons other than pure net gain for claiming American Indian ethnicity or could have misjudged the net gain even if that was her goal.

As a side note, if you are willing to narrow the joke to trying to say that Elizabeth Warren does not believe that white privilege is so broad, and that her actions prove this opinion, then you still run into an unsubstantiated assumption of motive. Warren could have a variety of reasons for claiming American Indian heritage, not necessarily one seeking an advantage. Most charitably, she might have actually thought she was American Indian, and stated so as a plain matter of (honestly incorrect) fact.

> ... why did Elizabeth Warren ***continuously*** pretend to be...

This is simply unfactual. I suppose it's a faulty premise, if you want to be technical.
Although Elizabeth Warren formally claimed multiple times to be an American Indian, it seems that she went through most of her life being considered "white".

> just a joke

Jokes really more on inference and emotion than formal logic, so you can't call it a fallacy.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a fallacy, because it's not a logical proof.

The point of comedy isn't to prove or disprove something using logical rigour, it's to entertain - and, in as close as it comes to the point of the question - to make the audience think about something they may have never questioned.

There's no question that there's a long history of racism, sexism, religious intolerance, homophobia, and many another 'ism' in America.  It's an article of faith that it's always the guy that suffers from none of those forms of discrimination that's responsible for and benefiting from all of them.

But, really, it's a rare person, maybe even a metaphorical 'unicorn' who faces no discrimination of any kind, from any quarter, his whole life.

Really, in that sense, the joke can be taken as an invitation to think about intersectionality.

Answer (score 1):

First I'm going to answer the question asked by this meme as I think it's important to understand this in order to understand the propaganda intent in the meme, after all this is what a meme is: If White Privilege exists then why did Elizabeth Warren pretend to be an Indian?

Well, why does the Queen 'pretend' to be English when the royal house:

> of Windsor is of German paternal descent and was originally a branch of the House of Saxe-Coburg and Gotha. This derived from the House of Wetin, which succeeded the House of Hanover to the British monarchy following the death of Queen Victoria, the wife of Albert, Prince Consort.

Obviously she is British and a symbol of Britishness and she's not pretending to be British. The Royal family adopted Britishness to identify themselves with the British people.

I don't know why Elizabeth Warren considered herself as a Native American, she herself hasn't said so. Identity is a fraught area. However, given what I have written above, a possible explanation may be she simply sees Native Americans as - well - native to the American continent. And she wants to identify herself with that. But until she actually says so, we won't know.

As to what kind of fallacy this is - I'm not sure that it even matters. and perhaps you might want to ask yourself why take the trouble to identify what kind of fallacy it is? Identifying fallacies is generally a kindergarten exercise which we teach novices in the ways of reasoning (and lack of reasoning) to help them on the way to actual reasoning.

The meme appears to suggest that Indian privilege exists otherwise why would an influential person, such as Senator Elizabeth Warren identify herself with them. This mischaracterises why people identify themselves with particular groups of people. Often it is not because they are privileged, but because they empathise with them. For example, Franz Fanon identified himself with the Algerian resistence against the settler colonialism of French Algeria.

Comment: She identified as Cherokee, not native to the continent, apparently because of some oral tradition within her family claiming that, no further proof and as far as I know she didn't claim otherwise. She made a gene test which is controversial in it's own right as to whether it's a cultural ethnicity or one based on genes and it showed some genes related to native americans but at levels so low that it would apply to most people living in america today. There's debate over whether she misused the identification to score minority reparation privilege but there's no confirmation about that.

Answer (score 1):

The woman has white privilege. Having one grand grand grand grand grand grandparent being Native American does nothing to her white privilege.

On top of that she wants “Native American” privilege. On its own, Native American privilege isn’t of much value, she wouldn’t swap both privileges. But it adds. “Look at me, im a poor persecuted woman, everyone discriminates against me because I’m a Native American” is supposed to give her sympathy *in addition of her white privilege of not being persecuted or discriminated against at all*.

PS. About the headline: Calling a Native American "Indian" sounds very very strange to me. Both Indians and Native Americans will be anywhere between confused and insulted hearing that.

Comment: i think this is right. i was disappointed not to find a fallacy for 'many things': an idea that all things are one so external inconsistency means internal inconsistency. it's not exactly against the law of contradiction anyway

Comment: I've been trying to come up with a question about the concept of Privilege, but not getting very far. Like: "*What the heck is* water?" We'll see if I manage it.

Comment: @gnasher729 I think the "Indian" has something to do with Columbus looking for a shortcut to India and discovering America and thus calling the natives "Indians" because of that. It's an obvious misnomer but has stuck around and as far as I know I've even seen examples of Native Americans using that label. Though for actual Indians it's probably as confusing as "African American" to a person from Africa like Elon Musk.

Answer (score 0):

**SHORT ANSWER**

It is certainly fallacious since it meets the definition of being persuasive and some combination of unsound and invalid, but it is difficult to discern through the presentation. I'd argue that this meme rises to the level of propaganda given the thoroughness with which it exploits cognitive biases. (See this article on [how foreign intelligence services manipulate social media](https://news.clearancejobs.com/2017/09/12/foreign-intelligence-services-used-social-media-to-target-clearance-holders/).

---

**LONG ANSWER**

There are multiple fallacies at play here, and despite Conifold's thorough answer above, I thought I might introduce a slightly different way of thinking about this image.

First, cognitive biases are at play. The image suggests the question is asked by the man in the image, but unless it can be substantiated, that is an unproven assumption. If this question featured Vladimir Putin in the background, it would create a much different effect. Secondly, it is in the form of a rhetorical question, and [Betterridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betteridge%27s_law_of_headlines) noted, this is a good indicator in headlines of newspapers that the question is specious and created to avoid accusations of defamation.

But setting aside the wrapper the argument is packaged in, let's unpack.

A charitable interpretation (see [deep structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_structure_and_surface_structure)) is that this rhetorical question is a deductive argument with one explicit and one implicit premise:

> - 1) Warren intentionally claimed an identity she does not possess
> - 2) (Claiming a puportedly inferior indentity when one possess a superior one is proof the superior one enjoys no advantage)
> - 3) Therefore, the superior identity is not superior.

To accuse Warren of intentionally misrepresenting herself (see [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon's_razor)) is [ad hominen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem). To presume the second premise is [non-sequitur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_fallacy) (see [social privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_privilege)). 3) To combine premises one and two is a sort of fallacy fallacy since it implies Warren is committing a fallacy and therefore the conclusion must be false.

Comment: I dont know what hes implying. But it’s certainly a fallacy lol

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, it is Locke's argumentum ad hominem, which while often unhelpful need not be fallacious

> The argumentum ad hominem, as Locke defined it, has subsequently
> developed into three different fallacies. His original description was
> that it was a way “to press a man with consequences drawn from his own
> principles or concessions.” That is, to argue that an opponent’s view
> is inconsistent, logically or pragmatically, with other things he has
> said or to which he is committed. Locke’s observation was that such arguments do not advance us towards truth, but that they can serve to promote agreement or stall disagreement. To argue that way is not a fallacy but **an acceptable mode of argumentation**.

It's a fallacy because the concessions drawn from (many) supporters of 'white privilege' do not actually include the consequence that (claiming) Native American heritage is never useful. If that consequence did exist to 'white privilege', then it would "inconsistent... with other things... to which he is committed", the fact Warren (presumably) found it useful.

So you can call it a straw man argumentum ad hominem.

---

In general, it seems to represent the ideal that all inconsistency is fatal to a position, even if the opponent's view - perhaps every supporter of the view - excludes the inconsistency. Such are straw men.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a logical fallacy. It is a joke. It is also factually incorrect. More importantly, it is political opinion. If white privilege exists... is tendentious. Memes are not arguments, they are the lowest common denominator of intellectual deprivation.

Answer (score -1):

That fallacy is called by many names, including: [Fallacy of many questions, complex question, fallacy of presuppositions, trick question, multiple question, loaded question, false question, *plurium interrogationum.*](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/69/Complex-Question-Fallacy).  That is, it makes a presupposition that many people would not accept.  (“Elizabeth Warren would have described herself as white if white privilege existed.”)  There’s also the problem that “white privilege” means different things to different people and in different contexts.

Specifically, most Republicans ([69% of them in a poll on October 23, 2019](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2019/10/23/three-years-after-trumps-win-many-republicans-still-feel-like-they-are-losing-side-america/)) say that discrimination against white people is a more serious problem than discrimination against black people.  This percentage is “significantly higher” for people “who are white, over age 65 and who cite Fox News as their primary source of news.”  Someone who makes the same assumption would believe that Elizabeth Warren secretly agrees that white people have it worse than Native Americans and called herself that to advance her career.

However, [more than than three in five Democrats in 2019 do not believe that white people are discriminated against.](https://thehill.com/hilltv/what-americas-thinking/433270-poll-republicans-and-democrats-differ-strongly-on-whether-white)  To them, exoticizing herself gave her no advantage at all.  A Progressive would say that a white person who claims hypodescent from the Cherokee does not give up any advantages she has from her skin color, where she grew up, where she went to school, how much money her parents had, how suspicious the authorities were of her, or any opportunities a Native American born to a poor family on a reservation would not have received equally.  That is, they don’t think the question makes any sense, because they would not agree that Elizabeth Warren ever gave up any of her white privilege.

Those possibilities are not logically exclusive.  There might be a situation where it’s advantageous both to grow up as a white person and to identify as something else.  Compare: “If it’s such a privilege to be a trust-fund baby, why do they all call themselves self-made men?”  You can even insert the name of another politician in there, if you feel like it.

Answer (score -1):

It's a rehtorical question, not an assertion of empeical fact.  There is no fallacy, because there is no assertion of fact other than that which is generally accepted.  Such as Warren clsiming to be an American Indian. Any falacy would have to lie with the accuracy of the claim that Warren presented herself as American Indian.

I should add that, having 32 decades of American (originated in Europe) lineage, that I fully affirm the rights of those who lived on these lands before my ancestors did, to survival and advancement of their people.

Comment: Then it's ok if they take it all back?

Answer (score -1):

The assertion of the image macro is that a rational actor such as Warren would not claim to be Indigenous if white privilege would be beneficial to Warren - therefore, one would think white privilege did not exist in some capacity. This line of thinking needs to be considered in ways other than just "logical fallacy".

Beyond logical fallacy, this argument falls apart if subject to an analysis of the way white privilege operates in a settler-colonial context.

In Eve Tuck and K. Wayne Yang's work "Decolonization is not a metaphor", they argue claims to indigeneity can act as a settler move to innocence that resolves the guilt of the colonizer whilst still allowing the colonizer to benefit from their occupation. Tuck & Yang even mention Warren directly as an example of this phenomenon.

> In this move to innocence, settlers locate or invent a long-lost ancestor who is rumored to have had "Indian Blood," and they use this claim to mark themselves as blameless in the attempted eradications of Indigenous peoples.
>
> Settler  nativism,  or  what  Vine  Deloria  Jr.  calls  the  Indian-grandmother  complex,  is  a  settler move to innocence because it is an attempt to deflect a settler identity, while continuing to enjoy settler privilege and occupying stolen land.

The key distinction here is that Warren is only *playing* Indian - she does not sever from her whiteness and thus white privilege, but is instead attempting to claim indigeneity at the same time.

Although the reasons for Warren's claim to indigenous blood cannot be fully known from outside observation, this underlying dynamic makes it probable that her claims were for external/internal relief and political benefit.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy, and thanks for contributing with a question/response! If you haven't done so, please take a quick moment to take the tour. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour More specifics can be found in the help center. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: I wonder who is playing the Cowboy?